# VueJS Performance Questions

Tags: performance, vue.js

I'm working on a browser extension that uses Vue Cli with Vue Bootstrap. I've already optimized my Vue Bootstrap imports to only load the components and icons I use in the project. I also have lazy loaded route components, but I still see a long time to get to the created hook of my first component. Here's a code extract:

Main entry point

```
console.info("Loaded in " + (new Date().getTime() - global.start) + "ms")
require("@/App.js")
```

App.js

```
import Vue from "vue"
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/vue"
import { Integrations } from "@sentry/tracing"
import App from "@/App.vue"
import router from "@/common/router"
import store from "@/common/store"
import { get } from "@/common/api"
...

import {
  ModalPlugin,
  ButtonPlugin,
  TabsPlugin,
  DropdownPlugin,
  AlertPlugin,
  ToastPlugin,
  FormInputPlugin,
  FormRadioPlugin,
  ...
  BIconArrowRightShort,
  BIconArrowDownSquareFill,
} from "bootstrap-vue"

Vue.use(ModalPlugin)
Vue.use(ButtonPlugin)
Vue.use(TabsPlugin)
...

Vue.component("BIcon", BIcon)
Vue.component("BIconX", BIconX)
Vue.component("BIconArrowLeft", BIconArrowLeft)
Vue.component("BIconMailbox", BIconMailbox)
Vue.component("BIconFolderPlus", BIconFolderPlus)
Vue.component("BIconEnvelope", BIconEnvelope)
...

global.vm = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  created() {
    this.$router.push({ name: "Responses" })
...
  })
}
```

And here's my component file that gets loaded first:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
let now = new Date().getTime()
console.info("SFC file loaded in " + (now - global.start) + "ms")
import ... from "@/common/components/..."

export default {
  ...
  mounted() {
    let now = new Date().getTime()
...
</script>

<style lang="scss">
...
</style>
```

When I benchmark times, this is what I get:

- SFC file loaded at 46ms (at the top of the script section)
- Created Hook starts a 177ms
- Mounted Hook starts at 308ms

I'm wondering what takes so long in the created hook (I don't do much, just checking the $route parameters). 150ms to just go through the created hook seems like a lot?

Here's the created hook:

```
console.info("Created Hook in " + (new Date().getTime() - global.start) + "ms")
    if (this.$route.params.xx {
      this.... = this.$store.state.xxxx.find(e => {
        return e.uuid == .......
      })
    }
```

Performance loading the extension is important for the user experience, and it always feels a little sluggish when opening the extension popup.

Any idea on what could delay the loading like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I notice is that you are doing a `route.push` on App created hook, that means that the router already solve the first route (probably '/') and after that you are adding another route (but not immediately) and then the router is solving that new route.

For a faster boot why don't you add a redirect to the route:

```
//...routes
{
 path: '/',
 redirect: {name: 'Responses'}
}
```

If you have the opportunity to change to Vue3 then maybe you could also perceive a performance boost since Vue2 has an always present GlobalAPI and Vue3 is doing a tree shaking and ignoring the unused stuff after building.

Note: Make sure you are testing it with a production environment, because if you are using the vue-cli to serve the content then the startup will include a lot of overhead

Answer (score 0):

There is much more what happens between `created` and `mounted` hooks - it's not just the code in all `created` hooks what is running. Check the Vue component [lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)

As you are using Vue SFC'c and probably Webpack, template compilation is out of the question but still, after `created` Vue is executing `render` functions of all components (producing VDOM) and creating real DOM elements based on VDOM (rendering whole app). So depending on number of components and elements, 150ms is not that bad...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! Actually the default route is already redirecting to Responses, and removing the push doesn't change much.

Unfortunately I can't really migrate to Vue 3 as I rely on dependencies that do not fully support Vue 3 (Vue BS being an important one).

I'm guessing that's as much as I can do at this point. Just wondering if there's any way with Vue Cli to open the window browser extension popup immediately and load Vue afterwards (right now, it's waiting for the whole thing to be loaded and then opens the popup which gives a 300ms delay between the click and the window actually opening).